# How to wait visibilityOfElementLocated for sub element?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am struggling with the syntax of `visibilityOfElementLocated`

I have an element for a table row, now I need to search an element in this row like `row.findElement(xxx)`

Below is syntax we use for locating element(parent) directly on page

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 90L);
WebElement data=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath
                ("./td[" + columnIdx + "]");
```

So question is how to use above wait on tableRow ?? (e.g. tableRow.(wait.until))

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have already defined webelement `row` and you want to find child/descendant `td` element inside this `row` you can replace

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 90L);
```

with

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(row, 90L);
```

Comment: I don't think WebDriverWait Constructor supports this one.. I tried but got , can not be applied compiler error

Comment: I didn't try it with `Java`, but this is how it works with `Python`... Can you update your ticket with full code? show how did you implement `WebDriverWait(row, 90L);`

Comment: Thanks Andersson for the direction. I have not yet implemented it as I am stuck on the syntax. I don't think we need full code here if I am able to explain my requirement here. Let me know if you need clarification on that

Comment: I meant I want to see that part of code when you use `WebDriverWait()` in the way I suggest as you said that you tried it... I'm interesting whether `Java` and `Python` implementations are different

Comment: Java supports only three type of constructors `1.  public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds)  ,  2.public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis) & 3.  public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Clock clock, Sleeper sleeper, long timeOutInSeconds,
      long sleepTimeOut)`

Comment: this doesn't work. Suggested functionality is not supported

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elementToBeClickable` in place of `visibilityOfElementLocated`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wb, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("value")));
```

This will wait for every web element for 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Anuj. But this not what I am looking for. I have a fixed parent element. Now I want to wait for child on this parent element.

Comment: Could you provide the html?

Comment: Sorry but can not. Something similar to @Andersson 's below answer. It's like parent -> wait.until.condition.child-locator

Answer (score 0):

You could also use *presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy* function:

```
WebElement childElem = wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(parentElem, By.xpath(xpath)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure out solution for this problem too.

The parameter to `wait.Until` method is in C# just a method with following signature `Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement>` (i.e. function with one parameter - the driver - returning the found element.

So instead of trying to hack the Selenium library, I don't have to call the predefined `ExpectedConditions` (like `ExpectedConditions.ElementExists`) methods and I can only pass function that does what I need.

```
var parent = ... // an element I want to start the search from
// find the element using the XPath expression starting at the parent element
wait.Until(driver => parent.FindElement(By.XPath("..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions here worked for me.

For Java or C# I just rewrote it as a single selector. So if the original (impossible) code you wanted to achieve is something like the following:

```
var tableRow = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tr:nth-child(3)"));
var wait = new WebDriverWait(tableRow , new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
var td = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector("td:nth-child(1)");
```

Just change it to a single selector and do your webdriver wait on that.

```
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
    var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector("tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(1)")));
```

You should be able to do the same kind of thing with XPaths too

Answer (score -1):

how about this, you can find the child element using the parent element.

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(row.findElement(By.xpath("./td[" + columnIdx + "]"))));
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking about. I guess this will solve my StaleElementReferenceException hopefully. Will give a try ! Thanks Gaurang mate

Comment: @ShekharSwami this is what you should do once you find your answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Yeah @GaurangShah! Let me try this approach. Once this works I will definitely accept & close this thread. :)

Comment: This won't work. The inner most statement will get executed first ... which is 'findElement' and you are using wait.Until in order to try to avoid using findElement which doesn't wait. Common mistake and will wreak havoc to your testing framework.